# How to get movie info from multiple IMDB ids using an API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, append

I've tried searching for this but I couldn't find any answer that would fit with the problem I'm facing.
I recently started playing with JQuery and all so this must be really stupid.

I have a div (.movie) that repeats itself throughout the page, each one with a specific id (#titanic, for example)

the information for title, year and runtime comes from a JSONP inside a function. so, inside each div I've called such function and defined which movie to search for.

```
<div class="movie" id="tt0050083">
  <script>
    id = tt0050083;
    getinfo();
  </script>
  <p class="title"></p>
  <p class="year"></p>
  <p class="runtime"></p>
</div>
```

the problem is, it does append the title, year and runtime to the last div only, not all of them. it gets all the different information for different movies, but everything is appended to the last div.

```
function getinfo(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://www.myapifilms.com/imdb?format=JSONP&idIMDB="+id,
            type:'GET',
            dataType:'JSONP',
            callback: 'callback',
            success: function(data, text, xhqr){
                $('#'+id).append( '<p class="title">' + data.title + '</p>' );
                $('#'+id).append( '<p class="year">' + data.year + '</p>' );
                $('#'+id).append( '<p class="runtime">' + data.runtime + '</p>' );
            }
        });
    }
```

the only valid id is being considered the last one I declared even though it searches for different movies each time I run `getinfo()`, it just appends on to the wrong place.

bet this is stupid but I've been banging my head for hours now
thanks!

Comment: i believe the success function is the problem...it will be better if tyou posted a part of your json output

Comment: you don't need to add inline javascript inside every div. Instead use jqueries each to loop through the movies in your success callback . How to do that we can't tell as you did not give an example of the received  json output.

Comment: Looks like only one id is being asked for and returned. `data.title`, etc. wouldn't work if an array was being returned. You would have to do something like `data[0].title`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a little inefficient to manually make divs. It is better to loop through your imdb ids and create the divs dynamically filled with the correct data. Here is a sample script I've just created.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/6z0nrq1w/5/)

```
var ids = ["tt0068646","tt0111161","tt0108052"];

getMoviesByimdbID(ids);

function getMoviesByimdbID(ar){
    var mymovies=$('#moviecontainer');
    for(i = 0; i<ar.length; i++){
        $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.myapifilms.com/imdb?format=JSONP&idIMDB='+ar[i],
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSONP'

        })
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var title= '<p class="title">'+data.title+'</p>';
            var year= '<p class="year">'+data.year+'</p>';
            var runtime= '<p class="runtime">'+data.runtime+'</p>';
            var urlPoster = '<img src="'+data.urlPoster+'">';
            mymovies.append('<div class="movie">'+title + year + runtime+urlPoster+'</div>');


        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        })
        .always(function() {
            console.log("complete");
        });


    }

}
```

Comment: this is better than i could have asked for. thanks, kasper. i noticed though that the order is quite random, not necessarily, the order i set for the ids. is there any way i could easily order them? thanks a bunch again

Comment: this is because the script makes an asynchronous request for each movie. So you don't really know in what order you will receive the movies. However I can fix it I'll adapt my answer.

Comment: here is a jsfiddle where the movies are in the same order as the array. However they will appear at an (almost) random order. http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/6z0nrq1w/6/

Answer (score 2):

You are making several requests to the movie api. These are asynchronous requests and the success callbacks are executed at a later time (once the api has responded). Your code does not wait for each response to return before making the next response. It moves on and sets the new global id and makes a new request. When the success callbacks are executed, the global "id" variable is set to the very last assignment that was made to it. That's why they are all being appended to the last div.

Try passing the id into getInfo() rather than setting a global variable.

For example, calling getInfo() would look like this:

```
id = 123;
getInfo(id);
```

And the definition of getInfo() would look like:

```
function getInfo(id) { 
..... 
}
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation, andew. made total sense to me and worked like a charm!